# Menu responsivo centralizado

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso que este menu esteja centralizado, pois todo meu site é centralizado.

Como fazer? Pois este menu está o tempo todo alinhado à esquerda.

Tento centralizar, mas perde o background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
text-align: center;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;
text-align: center;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
text-align: center;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #111;text-align: center;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;text-align: center;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 500;
    top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
text-align: center;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
text-align: center;
  }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.c("responsive");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: o seu código exemplo não se encontra formatado e dificulta a leitura. Por favor veja esta ajuda:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Cara, use o editor WebStorm da jetbrains. Vi que seu código está um pouco confuso, ele irá te ajudar muito.

Comment: Olá. Agradeço a atenção. Este código foi copiado do próprio w3schools. Na verdade, preciso apenas saber como fazer para centralizar todo o menu. Você sabe?

Segue codigo no w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Answer (score 1):

Substitua a classe `css`que atualmente está assim:

```
ul.topnav li {float: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

Por esta:

```
ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Veja em funcionamento: [Aqui](https://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/OXmZmb)

Comment: Olá. Puxa vida! Muito obrigado !!! Queria apenas perguntar uma coisa, eu tirei o float: none e funcionou centrlizado da mesma forma. Qual a função dele neste caso? É bom manter ou não?

Outra coisa: para que este código funcione no máximo de brwosers possível eui tenho que acrescenter o normalizr.css? Tem mais algum outro código que ajuda na compatibilidade? Abraços.

Comment: Olá @Wendell, na verdade fui testar melhor e parou de funcionar o botão que mostra o menu quando está responsivo. Não está mostrando, apenas está alinhado. O que será?

Comment: @Tesok se você olhar o próprio código que você postou, o menu responsivo já não funciona nele, mas não se preocupe, veja novamente [seu código em funcionamento aqui](https://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/OXmZmb) já com o menu responsivo funcionando!

Comment: Olá @Wendell. Ficou excelente! Não sei como agradecer. Gostaria de perguntar como posso estudar e me aprofundar como você, pela própria internet. Tenho dificuldades para entender o inline-block, inline--etc.... E algumas outras coisas, como quando usar firt-child, not, etc... 
Tudo isso vem da sua cabeça ? 
Como posso aprender?

Aproveito para perguntar se para funcionar com o máximo de compatibilidade possívei com outros browsers, o normalizr.css (conhecido) é suficiente? Ou tem outros includes que ajudam?

Abraços, amigo. Que você vá muito longe com esta sua generosidade.

Comment: @Tesok primeiramente não esqueça de colocar a sua pergunta como respondida. Você vai conseguir facilmente aprender usando tutoriais na internet. Eu recomendo você ir aprendendo aos poucos e treinando muito, não fique somente na teoria. Quanto ao `inline-block` existe a mesma dúvida parecida com a sua [aqui](http://goo.gl/iblsmj). O normalize.css é uma ótima alternativa pra normalizar os elementos nos mais variados navegadores, existe também a opção do CSS Reset, você pode ver uma comparação entre eles [aqui](https://goo.gl/6vkPPD).